# conemu macros 'line send delay' method?

Tags: bash, conemu, secure-crt

I frequently use SecureCRT and I really like it's 'line send delay' option. It lets you inject a delay in milliseconds to lines sent via mapped keys. This is really helpful because mapped keys sometimes send their commands too fast for the OS. Ex:

```
command1\ncommand2\n
```

needs to be entered as:

```
$command1
$command2
```

Not:

```
$command1
command2
$
```

From what I've learned ConEMU's Macros are pretty similar to SecureCRT's mapped keys. But, I have not figured out a "line send delay" option. Does anyone else know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Print("command1\n"); Sleep(1000); Print("command2\n")
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for.